# How enable and disable setTimeout onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, settimeout

I have a function that executes on page load.  The function executes every 30 seconds using setTimeout. I want to be able to enable and disable setTimeout onclick I have the following code below...

```
  <input id="vw" value="" type="hidden">
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('vw').value='0';>click here</a>

    <script>
    /* JAVASCRIPT BELOW */
    function mPb(){

    var vw = escape(document.getElementById('vw').value);

    if(vw == ''){//DO NOT SWITCH VIEW IF EMPTY

    var sTo = setTimeout("mPb()", 30000);

    } else {

    clearTimeout(sTo);  

    }

}//END VIEW MY FEED 

   //ON SERVICE LOAD DISPLAY SHITE INSTEAD OF ONLOAD  
   window.addEventListener ? 
   window.addEventListener("load",mPb,false) : 
   window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",mPb);
   </script>
```

Comment: ... the problem is he's missing a closing quote at the end of `onclick`: `onclick="document.getElementById('vw').value='0';"`

Comment: If it's executing every 30 seconds, shouldn't you be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you properly close your `onclick` attribute with a double quote:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('vw').value='0';">click here</a>
```

Also, here go two little suggestions to improve your code:

- If you're checking for an empty string inside your function, why setting the input value to `0` when you click the link? It works, but it would be more clear if you set the value to `''`.
- When using `setTimeout` (and `setInterval`), do not pass a string containing a function call. It works too, but it's [dangerous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21). Use this instead:

  ```
  var sTo = setTimeout(mPb, 30000);
  ```

Comment: code still not working...       
        `if(vw == ''){
         var sTo = setTimeout(mPb, 30000);
         } else {
         clearTimeout(sTo);  
              }`

Comment: Did you fix the quote on the link? The code does work, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WdSdQ/) and open the console to see a message being logged every second, until you click the link.

Comment: You are right my original code was working from the get go, but there seems to be a bug somewhere else in my code.  Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

sTo needs to go outside of the mPb function, that way you can reference it from you onclick.